# Can't rotate a table in prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm trying to put a large table in a pdf file which will be eventually used to take printout.

I want to render that table horizontally but can't find any option to do that.

I tried to rotate text using

```
pdf.text "text", :rotate => 90
```

but I can't use it within a cell. Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

I'm using prawn 0.12.0 and rails 3.2.0

Comment: If you can move that table to its own page, just create a landscape page and ignore any text rotation.  pdf.start_new_page(:layout => :landscape)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can move that table to its own page, just create a landscape page and ignore any text rotation.

```
pdf.start_new_page(:layout => :landscape)
```

(Was a comment, but outta make this an answer so other folks can see it as answered, and CodeMaster can keep his 100% answer rate... what was I thinking?)